# Crystal Reports Viewer (Refresh/Zoom/Export) Issue when Report orientation is set to landscape

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

I'm using crystal XI in my asp.net project.
For viewing reports i'm using **crystal reports web viewer** and it is working **fine** when the report orientation is set to **portrait**.When it is comes to landscape mode, the (Refresh/Zoom/Export/Next Pg) functions of the viewer shows **error** as given below.

[image]

Also i cant get other exception on my code behind or even firebug.
I'm using crystal reports run-time V13 under .NET framework 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

On a page change or refresh happen then the datasource accessed. It seems to be an issue with that. Could you check if you can Verify the database.

Go to Database > Verify DataSource